# Create Custom Class result set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get custom class instances as a result from a DB query:

```
class AEDHelper {
    static public function searchAED($position) {
        $var1 = $position['latitude'];
        $var2 = $position['longitude'];
        $var3 = $position['latitude'];

        $queryResults = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM TABLE"));

        $aedResults[] = new AED;

        foreach($queryResults as $result) {
            var_dump($result);
            $aed = $result;
            $aedResults[] = $aed;
        }

        return $aedResults;
    }
}
```

But I only receive the stdClass Objects. The transformerClass I use in my system requires a Responder Object. How can I get these objects as result from my query? I was trying to create them while looping through the result set. But this does not work. What would be the correct way?

**Responder Class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Events\EventGenerator;
use App\Events\ResponderWasAlarmed;

class Responder extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    protected $table = 'responders';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function incidents() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Classes\Incident');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change the behavior of your DB class which is actually fetching the DB results, or you need to implement some new functionality that will map an array into a Responder object.  Without knowing anything about those blocks of code, we aren't really going to be able to help you further than that.

Comment: I added my Responder Class. The DB is accessed by Eloquent in Laravel.

Comment: Going to need Model too :) Sorry, which framework is this?